# Replace foreign character codes in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm trying to edit a file with Swedish characters in Notepad++, but the Swedish characters when I view it in Unicode (was originally ANSI) show up as tiny black marks with parts of hex code in them, like xF6 for the Swedish character "ö".

How can I search and replace these hex marks with the actual characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the original file using it's original encoding of ANSI (AKA WinLatin1 CP1252)
- Open the "encoding menu"

  - do NOT chose "Encode in UTF-8"
  - instead choose "Convert to UTF-8"
- Save the file

I have tried this, it works for characters such as ÄØ which the "Encode in UTF-8" options shows as xC4xD8.